# WP7 application working only on emulator and on device when debugging

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have a problem with my WP7 application, it's working fine on the emulator and it's also working fine on the device but only when debugging. When I run the application when it's not debugging the application is terminated. No exception...nothing. 
I can not tell what part is actually causing that. The application is calling web services, bing map services and using GPS information. 
Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas without any code to see what you're actually doing

Comment: worst case: uncomment all parts you are not sure about. test. include one. test. include another. test. include another...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing anything expensive or synchronous during your startup?

You have a certain amount of time for your app to start up before the OS kills it.  with a debugger attached, you're exempted from the time limit.  On the emulator, your computer's processor speed might make allow it to start up faster than it would on the device.

I'd start simplifying your app startup and see if that's part of it.

Comment: The problem was exactly that! I simplified the start up and it's working fine now.

Comment: For me too. A tip: Use properties instead of constants when creating expensive objects (for me, it was a song from a file). This causes lazy loading and therefore a faster startup.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing some logging to a file in isolated storage as startup steps are executed to see how far your app is getting before it crashes. You can compare this to the log output when you run in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if a variable is not at the correct scope (as in a bug in your code), it can work in the emulator / debug on the phone, but won't run normally on the phone. Ensure your webservice is declared at the highest level possible (public for the page).

Answer (score 0):

I once spent hours trying to establish what was wrong with my app in a very similar situation, and it turned out that quitting Visual Studio and restarting it solved it. :(

Chris